# Why isn't my HTML source code not recognizing my open td tags?

Tags: html

For some weird reason, when viewing the source code on my HTML file there is an ending td tag that is colored red. When I hover over it I get a notice saying "End tag "td" seen but there are no open elements".

My browser output it fine, but my HTML is not being converted to a PDF format because of this syntax issue.

Can anyone please help me find a solution?? Thanks!!

```
    <table id='order_info_container'>
   <tr><td>
    <img id='o_summary_logo' src='o_summary_logo.png'>
    </td>

    <td id='customer_service'>
    <b>Customer Service # (212)-233-5751<br>
    Thank you for your business
    </td> //My source code is telling me that there is no open tag for this ending tag?
    </tr></table>
```

Comment: Because you didn't close the `<b>` tag.

Comment: Because you haven't closed your `<b>` tag.

Comment: Close the img and <b> tag

Comment: Have you checked your code for any other typos? Maybe there is another tag not closed, take `<b>` for example.

Comment: Why isn't it not? So it is recognizing then ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you didn't close your bold tag

```
<td id='customer_service'>
   <b>Customer Service # (212)-233-5751<br>
              Thank you for your business</b> <!---- here -->
</td>
```

Comment: Also, an alternative answer is "Don't use <b> tags, use CSS"

Comment: Okay. I there a reason why to use CSS vs <b> tags?

Comment: Using CSS instead of old-style formatting tags makes it easier to manage how your page(s) looks, especially as your pages grow larger, or more in number.  Also, since the HTML and CSS get loaded (and cached) separately, it can improve load times.

Answer (score 4):

```
<b>Customer Service # (212)-233-5751<br>
```

Should be

```
<b>Customer Service # (212)-233-5751</b>
```